# Data not passing from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

The program has a `DisplayActivity` class which receives data from `LoginActivity` class. The `DisplayActivity` has a `Fragment` to display the data passed from `LoginActivity`. 
The problem is that the `Bundle` that `DisplayFragment` class receives is null.So the data is not displaying in `Activity`. I am attaching the code. Kindly highlight the error.

**`DisplayActivity` class-**

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Button editButton;

    private static Bundle infoBundle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        infoBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        DisplayFragment details = new DisplayFragment();
        details.setArguments(infoBundle);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_details, details).commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("DisplayScreen");

        editButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
        editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent backIntent = new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                backIntent.putExtras(infoBundle);
                startActivity(backIntent);
                finish();
            }

        });
    }
```

**`DisplayFragment` class-**

```
public class DisplayFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Bundle backBundle;
    private TextView mTextView;
    public DisplayFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        backBundle = getArguments();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        if(backBundle != null) {
            String username = backBundle.getString("UserName");
            String emailID = backBundle.getString("E-mail");
            String gender = backBundle.getString("Gender");
            String city = backBundle.getString("City");

            mTextView = inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.user_text);
            mTextView.setText(username);
            mTextView.append("\n");
            mTextView.append(emailID + "\n");
            mTextView.append(gender);
            if (!city.equals("---Select---"))
                mTextView.append("\n" + city);
        }
        return inflatedView;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code you use to put the data in the `Intent` and start `DisplayActivity`

Comment: Check the bundle in Activity whether it contains something or not. If it's `null` then check from where it's coming from.

Comment: The problem is solved. Actually the text was getting overlapped on the toolbar so it was not visible. Data is displaying now after changing the flawed design. Though if I remove-  if(backBundle != null) statement, NullpointerException occurs. thanks for your concern Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving the complete code of LoginActivity, DisplayActivity and DisplayFragment where DisplayFragment receives the value which is passed from LoginActivity via DisplayActivity. Try this

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("name", "My name is ABCD");
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);
                i.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

DisplayActivity:

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Button editButton;

        private Bundle infoBundle;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);


            infoBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

            Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
            /*infoBundle = new Bundle();
            infoBundle.putString("name", "ABCD");*/
            DisplayFragment details = new DisplayFragment();
            details.setArguments(infoBundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, details).commit();

        }
    }
```

and DisplayFragment:

```
public class DisplayFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Bundle backBundle;
    private TextView mTextView, tvValue;

    public DisplayFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        backBundle = getArguments();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

        if (backBundle != null) {
            String username = "";
            username = backBundle.getString("name");


            tvValue = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.tvValue);
            tvValue.setText(username);

        }
        return inflatedView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Please add **permission** in your AndroidManifest.xml for LoginActivity and DisplayActivity